# Is "a-okay" acceptable in lowercase?

Tags: capitalization, compounds

Interestingly, Merriam-Webster has an entry for "A-OK" but not for "A-okay."

Most other dictionaries I have referenced have an entry for "A-okay" including Oxford Living Dictionaries, dictionary.com, TheFreeDictionary, and the Collins English Dictionary.

In all these cases the entry is "A-okay" with a capitalized A. In a few entries, some of the example sentences use a lowercase "a." And Vocabulary.com (https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/a-okay) even has the entry as all lowercase.

I'm using the word in dialogue within a manuscript. Are all three variations acceptable, or is one generally considered to be correct?

Comment: Why not go with the one most dictionaries agree on? Though doubtless those offering other versions have done their corpus research.

Comment: If you consider the autocorrect on stackexchange comments worth anything, typing A-Okay automatically corrects it to how I have it written right now.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I simply like the way it looks in lowercase.

Comment: The question is, if you type it in all lower-case, will people still consider it to be A-OK?

Comment: @HotLicks - Yes. "People" meaning an agent. :-)